# Ajax.BeginForm OnSuccess, onBegin , OnFailure not firing

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

No matter what I try none of javascript methods is not firing/working.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Errors (string name, string email)
{
    //send email
        return new JsonResult()
        {
            Data = new { result = "success" },
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
        };
}
```

Partial View

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(
    "Errors", 
    "Home", 
    new AjaxOptions { 
        HttpMethod = "POST", 
        OnSuccess = "onSuccess ", 
        OnFailure = "OnFailure", 
        OnBegin = "Begin()" }, 
    new { @class = "form-horizontal",  id = "error-form" }))
{
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Your name</label>
          <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" value="@name" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Your e-mail</label>
          <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" value="@email" />
        </div>



        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" style="margin-bottom:4em;">Send message</button>
      }

      <div class="form-group" id="thankYou" style="display:none">
        <label>Thank you!</label>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function Begin() {
    alert("b");
  }

  function onSuccess(data) {
    debugger;
    alert(data.result);
  };

  function OnFailure(data) {
    debugger;
    alert(data.result);
  };

  $(document).ready(function () {

  });

</script>
```

All I get is a response in JSON format.  See [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4dcc.png). No event is fired. Any ideas?

Comment: Is that razor syntax? please add that tag. You'll prob have better luck getting a reply if you format the code so people don't have to scroll right at all, especially to see the most important part of the code; and remove all extra stuff -- styles, classes, scripts, blank lines -- only include what's absolutely necessary to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

[Ajax.BeginForm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.beginform?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) has 11 overloads... your parameters does't match any of them. I assume you want to use [this overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.beginform?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_Ajax_AjaxExtensions_BeginForm_System_Web_Mvc_AjaxHelper_System_String_System_String_System_Web_Routing_RouteValueDictionary_System_Web_Mvc_Ajax_AjaxOptions_System_Collections_Generic_IDictionary_System_String_System_Object__):

```
BeginForm(AjaxHelper, String, String, RouteValueDictionary, AjaxOptions, IDictionary<String,Object>)
```

You need to add `RouteValueDictionary` to your parameters:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(
    "Errors",                     // <--action name
    "Home",                       // <--controller
    null,                         // <-- RouteValueDictionary
    new AjaxOptions {             // <-- AjaxOptions
        HttpMethod = "POST", 
        OnSuccess = "onSuccess ", 
        OnFailure = "OnFailure", 
        OnBegin = "Begin()" }, 
    new {                         // <-- htmlAttributes
        @class = "form-horizontal", 
        id = "error-form" }))
```